# Primefaces additional attribute with ajax event

Tags: ajax, spring, jsf, primefaces

I have this tabview component:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView"
        var="tab"
        dynamic="true"
        cache="true"
        value="#{integrationBean.tabs}">

        <p:ajax event="tabChange"
            listener="#{integrationBean.tabChanged}"
            update="tabContent"/>
```

And i need to pass attribute to the ajax request.
Something like

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange"
                listener="#{integrationBean.tabChanged}"
                update="tabContent">
<f:param name="id" value="#{integrationBean.id}" />
<!-- OR -->
<f:attribute name="id" value="#{integrationBean.id}" />
<!-- Neither of this works -->
</p:ajax>
```

So i can do

```
@Value("#{request.getParameter('id')}")
protected Long id;
```

on my bean.
How to pass this param to the request?

Comment: Your backing bean is Spring managed bean? What is the scope of that bean?

Comment: Yes, it is managed by spring, i am using approach from this article. http://www.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/

Comment: According to this article you are using view scope. Managed property (like `@View` annotated property in your example) is inject just after bean creation. You can't inject it later. In this AJAX request your bean is already created.

Comment: It is little bit more complicated. I have bean which handles this tabChange event and it load pages to the `ui:include` component. These loaded pages are using another beans in which i need this id.
`<p:layoutUnit id="tabContent"><ui:include src="#{integrationBean.template}" /></p:layoutUnit>` and the `integrationBean.tabChange`d method just set template property to the name of template to load.

Comment: Did you try JSF `@ViewScoped` and `@ManagedPropety` combination to achieve this instead of porting bean scope into Spring?

Comment: I could try, but it is not solution for me. And i think that would not help. The parameter is not send in the request itself.If the request would contain that parameter i would be abdle to obtain it somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<p:remoteCommand>`.

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" oncomplete="tabChangeCommand()" />
<p:remoteCommand name="tabChangeCommand" actionListener="#{integrationBean.tabChanged}" update="tabContent">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{integrationBean.id}" />
</p:remoteCommand>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<f:param/>` in your xhtml

```
<f:param name="id" value="#{integrationBean.id}" />
```

You can use [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29) to retrieve it from backing bean

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();

String paramValue= map.get("paramName");
```

Comment: I know how to get params from request. Problem is that there is no param "id" in request. So in this case paramValue is null.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved it by putting id in flash scope and getting it back in ajax requests. It is not ideal solution, but it works.

Comment: You'll lose it in case of validation/conversion failures on the same form.